# When to use EFS over FSx?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs, amazon-fsx

I have read through the documentation for the usecases of EFS and FSx but still i'm confused as to when to use one over the other.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: The primary difference is that EFS supports Linux and FSX supports Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EFS is cheaper than FSx.

Some AWS services only support using EFS (AWS Lambda, Linux ECS containers).

Some AWS services only support using FSx (Windows ECS containers).